# Amazon Web Service Deployment - free tier

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use the AWS free tier for host a java web application. I created an EC2 instance but i don't figure out how can I deploy the application to this instance. I was trying to use the AWS Toolkit for eclipse to deploy the web site to Elastic Beanstalk, but from here i need a second tier to deploy the application to the production. 
My question is: What is the free solution to make a deploy to my EC2 instance and how?
Thank you!

Comment: wait, why do you need two tiers? You've only talked about a "java web application", no other tiers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Elastic Beanstalk ( which I recommend), then you should create the Beanstalk stack manually from the AWS console. Before you do that, I suggest you to terminate your other instance, because you wont use that.
The beanstalk stack will create an EC2 instance in the background, also an RDS database if you ask for it. You pay for the resources ( EC2, RDS), but no extra cost for the "Beanstalk stack".
After you having the Beanstalk stack, you can deploy it with the Eclipse plugin, or just simply generate the WAR file and upload it via the AWS console. ( On the Beanstalk page there is a place to upload a war file for deployment.)

Be aware to set the DB connection details to the RDS ( if you are using it).

Also note that the free tier is nice to warm up but not recommended for production.

When you create the Beanstalk stack make sure you create a single AZ web frontend, so you will have only 1 webserver running.